# Configuration 'development' is not set in the workspace Angular

Tags: angular

I am working on an application in which i am using angular 12, when i start the application using npm start but it is showing error **Configuration 'development' is not set in the workspace** even though it is declared in **"serve"** in **Angular.json** file.
Attached is the angular json file for better understanding.
**Angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "5eafdd9a-9c8e-4012-82da-62ece7b12207"
  },
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "frontend-Hedgex": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/frontend-Hedgex",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/custom.js",
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "devnet": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.devnet.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "stage": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.stage.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "frontend-Hedgex:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "frontend-Hedgex:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "frontend-Hedgex:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "frontend-Hedgex"
}
```

**any solution please ?**

Comment: Did the solution provided fix your issue? If not what error are you getting now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your configuration name for dev environment is different from the name in the `serve`. `devnet` vs `development`, try changing it so the names are the same.

```
"configurations": {
   "production": {
      "fileReplacements": [
         {
            "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
            "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
         }
      ],
   },
   "devnet": {
      "fileReplacements": [
         {
            "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
            "with": "src/environments/environment.devnet.ts"
         }
      ],
   },
   ...
   ...     
   "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
         "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "frontend-Hedgex:build:production"
            },
            "devnet": {
              "browserTarget": "frontend-Hedgex:build:devnet"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "devnet"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "frontend-Hedgex:build"
          }
        },
```

Comment: Stoobish: Thank you bro..it worked...have a nice day..... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "frontend-Hedgex:build:production"
        },
        "development": { <-- remove this line
          "browserTarget": "frontend-Hedgex:build:development" <-- remove this line
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "development" <-- remove this line
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answer given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.